# How to add a global variable into map operation?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In scala, I tried to pass a huge global variable into map operation, spark prompted me with information:

```
ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
```

Code is like:

```
val data = sc.textFile(inputPath).cache()
val map = Map[String, Int]()
for (i <- 0 to 9) {
    map(i.toString) = i
}
data.map(sample => {
    if (map.contains(sample)) {
        ("Found")
    }
    else {
        ("Not found")
    }
})
```

Comment: I think you need to broadcast the map.
try val broadcastedMap = sc.broadcast(map)
and access it with broadcastedMap.value

Comment: Tried, still encountered the same error...

Comment: Why are you serializing *huge* objects?

Comment: No serialization, just re-define Array[Map[String, Int]] as broadcast, still failed

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved, I adjust data type from "Array[Map[String, Int]]" into "Map[String, Int]"